# javascript || operator gives different results based on order

Tags: javascript

I understand a||b returns an object, not boolean value. I just can't figure out why javascript gives different results for

```
undefined || "" (result is "")
"" || undefined (result is undefined)
```

which I think both should return "".
Can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Update: it is answered clearly by @Quentin, "" is evaluated as false, and a||b will return b if both a and b are evaluated as false.

Comment: what are you checking exactly? Can you provide a code snippet with a bit more of a context?

Comment: FYI: JavaScript's `||` operator doesn't return you a boolean.  That's probably why you are confused.

Comment: you are right, I was confused by it :) good  catch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `||` operator tests the truthiness of the left hand side of the expression. If the LHS is a true value, then it returns the LHS, otherwise it returns the RHS.

You can see how this combines with an `if` for a practical example:

```
if (a || b)
```

- If `a` is true, then it is the same as `if (a)` which is `if (true)`.
- If `a` is false and `b` is true, then `if (b)` is `if (true)`
- If `a` and `b` are both false, then it is `if (b)` which is `if (false)`

If your example, neither `""` nor `undefined` are true values, so both of your tests will return the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript's logical OR operator, `||`, [returns one of its operands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). In `a || b`, it returns `a` if `a` is truthy, and `b` otherwise.

Both of your arguments evaluate as `false`. So in `undefined || ""`, it returns `""`. For `"" || undefined`, it returns `undefined`. In both cases, it's because that's what's in the `b` position.

Answer (score 1):

The || operator returns the first argument that evaluates as true. If all the arguments are false then it just returns the last argument, whatever it may be.